# Get direct child with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

When I want get the direct child with querySelectorAll I have this error :

```
Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '> li' is not a valid selector.
```

Js

```
const lang = document.querySelector('.lang');
const items = lang.querySelectorAll('> li');
```

I don't understand why.
If I add this selector: '* > li' it works but I do not find that logical the root element is lang node.

Comment: `>` is a _combinator_, and therefor you need a thing on the left side and a thing on the right side of it, because those two parts are what this _combines_ in the first place.

Comment: Well, simply because as the error states - it is not a valid css selector.

Comment: So is not a fully CSS selector because in CSS it is possible to make '> li' from a parent element. Here my parent is lang node.

Comment: In my case the best way is to use the ParentNode property Children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
const lang = document.querySelector('.lang');
const items = lang.querySelectorAll('li');
```

Now `items` will be all `li` inside `.lang`, that's how `querySelectorAll` works.

Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll)

Why `> li` did not work? Because it's not a valid css selector

Why `* > li` works? Because it's a valid css selector. Moreover every `li` in any valid html code will always be inside `ul` or `ol` so technically; writing `* > li` is same as writing `li`

**UPDATE :**
For only first level `li` try this:

```js
let lang = document.querySelector(".lang");
let firstLevelLis = 
     Array.from(lang.querySelectorAll("li"))
     .filter(node => node.parentNode === lang)

for(let li of firstLevelLis){
  li.querySelector("span").style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

```html
<ul class="lang">
  <li><span>Foo</span></li>
  <li><span>Bar</span></li>
  <li><span>Baz</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Don't make me red<span></li>
      <li><span>Neither me</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My problem is that I have nested list but I need only the first level. That's why I thought about `> li`.

Comment: Thank you Devansh

Comment: Welcome Steven! :)

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector` is a function after all. You can't combine the object with the parameter. You would need to edit the function body to do that. Which means it's not possible to do such thing here.

The only possible close alternative would be

```
var parent = '.lang';
var child = document.querySelector(parent + ' > li');
```

Answer (score 1):

i found this: (using :scope as your parent reference(#parent))

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');

const children = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope > div');
console.log(children); // ️ [div.child, div.child]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="child">
        Child 1
        <div>Nested Child 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="child">
        Child 2
        <div>Nested Child 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

from https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-queryselectorall-get-direct-children